How to set poinths to cuvers to merge curves based on the closest distance

How to set the curve to be on the right side without cross linking, as the distance between the points on the right side will be smaller than the width of the two points in the middle. It is necessary to set a distance greater than this before not connecting them.

source file
enter link description here

I think this could work: 1. Selectively join points using geometry nodes. 2. Capture Mesh Island. 3. Convert vertices to points (not sure if this is needed, if not, then 2. is also not needed). 4. Points to Curves using (captured) mesh island as group ID.

Thank you for your answer. I have tried dividing line segments into many different ones, and I want to minimize the number of segments. 2 or 3 segments are also acceptable, but this method requires more than 10 line segments.

You mention you want to base it on distance. So you can use the linked answer to select points within given instance of each-other. Then just convert that to curves.

Thank you for your answer. I was just researching and I don't know why there are so many line segments. Can you help me download my source file and make a case study? Thank you very much. I have been studying this answer for several hours.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XNMfudMtFj2b0riR3yq426qWfxVr7TjU/view?usp=drive_link
